# jquery flot prints dates on the x-axis

Tags: jquery, python, django, flot

in django I am creating data series using `datetime.date()` objects, like this:

`data.append([ddate, daily_score])` (ddate is a datetime.date() object, daily_score is integer)

How can I format them in the jquery flot diagram in the following way?

"Day/Month"?

I am doing this:

```
xaxis:{
       mode: 'time',
       timeformat: '%d/%m',
       minTickSize: [1, "day"]
},
```

but I get no graph to display.

Comment: Could you do a printout of your data array that you pass to flot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [flot documentation](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt), you will see that the time format is supposed to be a Javascript timestamp, that is, milliseconds since [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch) (January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC). You pass a `datetime` object, so I guess that's your problem.

You can easily convert your dates to milliseconds since epoch though:

```python
import datetime
import time

msdate = time.mktime(datetime.date(2012, 5, 25).timetuple()) * 1000
```

After I wrote this suggestion I saw that the flot documentation also had a suggestion of how to do in python:

```
import datetime
import calendar

calendar.timegm(datetime.date(2012, 5, 25).timetuple()) * 1000
```

Otherwise your syntax looks ok from what I can tell.

Comment: thank you. Just a note. I think that if you use `calendar.timgm()` you do not need to multiply with 1000.

Comment: To get `time.mktime()` and `calendar.timegm()` to return results in the same order of magnitude, you have to multiply by 1000 (at least with my setup). However, they do not necessarily return the same result. [`time.mktime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.mktime) returns local time and [`calendar.timegm()`](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) returns UTC time, if I got the documentation right.